# SAX парсинг по тексу внутри тега

Tags: java, xml

Как с помощью текста внутри тега и названия тега которые были вбиты пользователем заставить выдать в консоль названия тегов и данные от вбитого тега до вбитого тега SAX методом. Да я знаю что SAX для этого не юзается ибо не запоминает раположение тегов но все же. Ну вот например я вбил "product with p03" и в данном случае изходя из XML должно выдатся 
product eee
    p01
    Product1
    100
Как это реализовать?

Вот XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product name="eee">
        <id>p01</id>
        <name>Product1</name>
        <price>100</price>
    </product>
    <product name="pp">
        <id>p02</id>
        <name>Product2</name>
        <price>200</price>
    </product>
    <product name="rr">
        <id>p03</id>
        <name>Product3</name>
        <price>300</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Запоминайте текущую вложенность тегов в стеке: когда встречается открывающий тег (startElement) - заносите в стек, когда встречается закрывающий тег (endElement) - выталкиваете из стека.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  а можно пример?